# How can I view function names and parameters contained in an ELF file?

Tags: linux, cygwin, elf

If I look at the file's bytes I can definately see some of the function names in there. 
Is there any tool that will list them for me?
Maybe even their parameters too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should print all defined symbols within your object file or library.

```
nm -C --defined-only file.o
```

`nm` has quite a lot of options that you could use to filter out the symbols like `-g` for displaying only `global symbols`, `-l` for printing the line number (if you had used `gcc -g` to enable debug symbols) and so on.

If you have an ELF format binary (looks to be your case), you could also use `readelf`

```
readelf -Ws file.o
```

The column number 8 in this output contains the symbol name which is of interest. You could use `c++filt` to demangle the name:

```
readelf -Ws file.o | awk '{print $8}' | c++filt
```